# Bugged React virtualized list issue

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, react-window, ui-virtualization

I'm developing a virtualized list using `react-window` and `react-virtualized` that renders a bunch of items, each one containing an image, a text element and a "download image" button - [here is a link to a sandbox of it](https://codesandbox.io/p/live/70dca664-ab47-4236-b95e-ab2ad7efcdd7).
As you can see, the first items of the list that render as soon as the list loads are rendered "fine", but as soon as you scroll down the list, the rendering of the other elements is all glitchy, buggy and most of them don't render at all. I can't seem to find what is wrong in the code's logic to be causing this bug, so any help from more experienced debuggers would be greatly appreciated!

React Version: 18.2.0
NPM Version: 9.8.1
Node.js Version: 20.9.0